# Calculating work integral of F on curve C

Tags: calculus, integration

I am told that the curve C is the intersection along $z=x^2+y^2$ and $x=1$ from $(1,2,5)$ to $(1,0,1)$ and the force field $F$ is defined by $F(x,y,z)=e^{yz}i+e^{y}j-e^{x}k$.

I am first asked to parameterise C. This is what I got:

Let $y(t)=-t$ since y and z are decreasing along the path, $x(t)=1$, thus $z(t)=1+t^2$. The range of $t$ is $-2\leq t\le 0$. Is this correct?

Now, F in terms of the parameter $t$ is:
$$F(t)=e^{-t(1+t^2)}i+e^{-t}j-e^{1}k$$

And $x'(t)=0$, $y'(t)=-1$ and $z'(t)=2t$

Thus, to calculate the work integral:

$$\int_{-2}^{0} -e^{-t}-e dt=1-e^{2}+2e$$

Have I done this correctly? Not sure if t can be negative and the work negative too.

Comment: Your calculations look good. Both $t$ and work can be negative. Here, $t$ is just a parameter, but had it been time it might have been allowed to be negative depending on the situation.

Comment: Obviously there's an error, as Robert Z has pointed out. Anyway, the method is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one small error in your evaluation. The work integral should be
$$\int_{-2}^{0}(e^{-t(1+t^2)},e^{-t},-e^{1})\cdot(0,-1,2t) dt=
\int_{-2}^{0}(-e^{-t}-2et)dt=[e^{-t}-et^2]_{-2}^0\\=1-e^2+4e.$$

P.S. Yes, the work can be negative (and the parameter too). Note that if $L$ is the work of a force field $F$ along a certain curve $C$ from point $A$ to point $B$ then the work from $B$ to $A$ along the same curve is $-L$.